# Inverse uncertain homography

Tags: matrices, geometry, probability-theory, inverse

Suppose x'= Hx, with x' and x homogeneous coordinates in an image and H a homography matrix. However, H is the result of calculations that take into account the uncertainty of x' and x, meaning H~{$\mu_H$, $\Sigma_{hh}$}, with h=vec(H). I follow the approach in the book Photogrammetric Computer Vision chapter 10, Reasoning with Uncertain Geometric Entities.
My question is: if x' and H are given (both mean and covariance matrix), how do I calculate x? I know x = H$^{-1}$ x'. But how does the uncertainty of H propagate through the inverse operation on H?

Comment: A slight ambiguity of your question is that the matrix defining an homography is known up to a multiplicative constant. When you write$ H^{-1}$ do you mean the inverse of the function or of the matrix? In the first case,  $x'=(ax+b)/(cx+d)$ implies $x= (-dx+b)/(cx-a).$ and this shows that the errors are of  the same kind (in a sense which could be made more explicit).